# How do I pass data from angular post to web api post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an angular post method through which I want to pass data to web api post but doesn't seem to work. 
What could I be doing wrong?

*customerPersistenceService.js*

```
var customerPersistenceService = function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        save: function(customer) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post("/api/customers", customer)
                 .success(deferred.resolve)
                 .error(deferred.reject);

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        update: function(customer) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.put("/api/customers/{id}" + customer.id, customer)
                 .success(deferred.resolve)
                 .error(deferred.reject);

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
};
```

*customerEditCtrl.js*

```
function customerEditCtr($stateParams, $location, customerPersistenceService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.editableCustomer = {};
    vm.selectedCustomerId = $stateParams.id;
    customerPersistenceService.getById(vm.selectedCustomerId).then(
        function (customer) {
            vm.editableCustomer = customer;
        });
    };

    vm.saveCommand = function () {
        if (saveCustomer) {
            var customer = vm.editableCustomer;
            customer.id = vm.selectedCustomerId;

            if (customer.id !== 0) {
                customerPersistenceService.update(customer).then(
                    function (result) {
                        return result.data;
                    });

            } else {
                customerPersistenceService.save(customer).then(
                    function (result) {
                        return result.data;
                    });
            }
        }
    };
};
```

In the *CustomerAPIController.cs* my methods look like these:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Customer newCustomer)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _customerService.AddNewCustomer(newCustomer);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, newCustomer);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }
}


[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody]Customer editableCustomer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }

    if (id != editableCustomer.Id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    try
    {
        _customerService.UpdateCustomer(editableCustomer);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "{success:'true', verb:'PUT'}");
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }
}
```

***Update:***
After some investigation, I realise the *vm.editableCustomer* seems to contain an array of all customer objects making it hard to pass to the Web API POST.
I fail to understand how this object gets assigned with all customer objects.

Comment: Your persistence js, you know that the `$http.put/post/delete/get` returns you a promise, so you don't have to include the `$q` library, and that the `$q` is in the `$http`

Comment: Look at this api routing on the asp.net website

Comment: I left  out the getById and getAll since they work.@Callum Linington

Answer (score 2):

There is a clear error:

```
$http.put("/api/customers/{id}" + customer.id, customer)
```

This will try to PUT to an url like this:

```
http://yoursite/api/customers/{id}927
```

You need to remove the `{id}` part, so that your url is correct:

```
http://yoursite/api/customers/927
```

The segment enclosed in braces only exists in the server side route template, and it's used to extract the parameter from the incoming URI.